# Heroku Buildpack Multi - no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: node.js, heroku, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS with NodeJS in a worker process in Heroku, but when I switched to  buildpack-multi, Heroku gives me this when I push:

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

Here is my .buildpack:

```
http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
http://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
```

I also have a package.json in my root directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your buildpacks file should be called `.buildpacks`, not `.buildpack`. See the [`detect`](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi/blob/master/bin/detect) script in [`ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi`](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to see what is needed for successful detection.